# TransactionScope on Multiple Threads

Tags: .net, ado.net, transactionscope, msdtc, plinq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TransactionScope and multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673530/transactionscope-and-multi-threading)

I'm using a TransactionScope so that I can rollback changes. I'm also using PLINQ on a IEnumerable of operations I want to perform.

Because the TransactionScope doesn't carry over to the new threads created by PLINQ, each operation is blocked by the TransactionScope on the original thread and the parallelized operations time out (at the ADO .NET level).

Is there any way around this or a way of carrying my TransactionScope onto a new thread? I don't mind escalating to MSDTC if that's what it takes.

Thanks.

Comment: code sample about it?