# In NServiceBus full duplex application Server could not send/reply/return message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, msmq, nservicebus

I have created a ASP.Net Web API project and using this [link](http://coderkarl.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/injecting-nservicebus-into-asp-net-webapi/). NServiceBus is integrated with web api. Here is my configuration at web api as a client.

```
        Configure.Serialization.Xml();
        Configure.Transactions.Enable();

        Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName(Constants.ClientName)
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .ForWebApi()
            .Log4Net()
            .UseTransport<Msmq>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

This is how I'm sending message to Server

```
         var response = await Bus.Send(Constants.ServerName, request)
            .Register<ResponseModel>((NServiceBus.CompletionResult completionResult) =>
            {
                ResponseModel responseMessage = null;
                if (completionResult != null && completionResult.Messages.Length > 0)
                {
                    var status = completionResult.Messages[0] as RequestStatus?;

                    if (status == RequestStatus.Successful)
                    {
                        responseMessage = TransactionManager.TransactionDictionary[request.RequestId].ResponseModel;
                    }
                }

                return responseMessage;
            });
```

This is how I'm sending response from Server. I have commented some lines to show what I have already tried.

```
    public void Handle(RequestModel message)
    {
        ProcessRequest(message).RunSynchronously();
    }

    private async Task ProcessRequest(RequestModel message)
    {
        ....
                ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();
                response.RequestId = message.RequestId;
                response.Result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                //Bus.Send(Util.Constants.ClientName, response);

                //Bus.Reply(response);

                //Bus.Reply<ResponseModel>((ResponseModel response) => 
                //{
                //    response = Bus.CreateInstance<ResponseModel>(r =>
                //    {
                //        r.RequestId = message.RequestId;
                //        r.Result = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                //    });
                //});

                await Bus.Send(Util.Constants.ClientName, response).Register((NServiceBus.CompletionResult completionResult) =>
                {
                    if (completionResult != null && completionResult.Messages.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var msg = completionResult.Messages[0];
                        if (msg != null)
                        {
                            var status = (RequestStatus)msg;
                            return status;
                        }
                    }
                    return RequestStatus.Error;
                });
         ....
       }
```

From any of the above response methods ultimately all messages end up in error queue.

Previously I was getting 'Could not enlist message' error. Now it is not throwing that error. But Server could not send message to Client.

I could not get what I'm doing wrong. Please also suggest if you see any scope for improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if TransactionScope work correctly with async/await in C#. According to this question ([Get TransactionScope to work with async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543254/get-transactionscope-to-work-with-async-await)) in .NET 4.5.1 there was introduced option for TransactionScope that enable mixing it with async/await. Unfortunately NServiceBus doesn't support .NET 4.5/4.5.1 so try just remove async/await.

Comment: Thanks Slawomir for quick reply. My concern is not about the receiving response at client but what I could not understand is why any of the response or send methods from server message handler class could not enlist or send the message to client msmq. It should normally works as its working at client end when I send the request message to server.

Comment: I got your point. I moved the response/send code from async method to handler and it starts working. Thanks Slawomir Rosiek.