# Entity Framework transactions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What is the best way to use(reuse) transactions in Entity Framework 6. 
Use case:
If we have two methods

```
public decimal Withdraw(string accNum, decimal amount) 
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var query = from t in db.MoneyTransactions
                    where t.AccountNumber.Equals(accNum)
                    select t;
        MoneyTransaction mt = query.First();
        mt.Amount -= amount;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return amount;
}

public void Put(string accNum, decimal amount)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var query = from t in db.MoneyTransactions
                    where t.AccountNumber.Equals(accNum)
                    select t;
        MoneyTransaction mt = query.First();
        mt.Amount += amount;
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

I want to use this methods separately(e.g. just put money in an account) and also use them in a single transaction:

```
public void Transfer(string srcAcc, string destAcc, decimal amount) 
{
    Withdraw(srcAcc,amount);
    Put(destAcc,amount);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into Systems.Transactions assembly and namespace. (Part of the BCL)

Then you can do something like this:

```
using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
    Withdraw(srcAcc, amount);        // No changes needed to these
    Put(destAcc, amount);            //   two methods...

    trans.Complete();
}
```

System.Transactions will create whats called an ambient transaction. This is a transaction stored on the thread, and any ADO.NET, LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework DB operations will use look for this `TransactionScope` object.

This transaction is either committed or rolled back at the end of the `using` block.
Calling `Complete()` on the TransactionScope object will trigger a commit in the database, while NOT calling `Complete()` will roll back the transaction instead.

Comment: EF provides transaction mechanisms, no need to use anything else for pure db transactions.

Comment: @Rodrigo: True, and System.Transactions makes it even easier to use it. Why would you not use System.Transactions for this?

Comment: Any idea how this code could use async/await? If the transaction is stored in the thread, this is quite a problematic scope...

Comment: @mot: Haven't tried it, but a quick search turns up this result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17527759/19594

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloaded methods:

```
public void Put(string accNum, decimal amount, MyDbContext context)
{
    var query = from t in context.MoneyTransactions
                where t.AccountNumber.Equals(accNum)
                select t;
    MoneyTransaction mt = query.First();
    mt.Amount += amount;
    db.SaveChanges();
}

public void Put(string accNum, decimal amount)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        Put(accNum, amount, db);   
    }
}
```

The same with `Withdraw` method. Then you could write:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        Withdraw(srcAcc, amount, db);
        Put(destAcc, amount, db);

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        tran.Rollback();

        throw;
    }
}
```

Thanks to overloaded methods you don't have to refactor other existing methods to apply new parameter (`MyDbContext`).