# Speed up integration test that hits real SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, nunit, integration-testing, sql-server-express

My application has a business layer that heavily talks to a database. This layer is implemented as a bunch of `ADO.NET` calls wrapped with `Dapper`. To initialise the database schema, I use `Entity Framework 6` Code First, which has a nice side-effect of being able to use my C# POCO both as DDL and DAO.

The raw SQL I use in `Dapper` is a mixture of plain old SQL, some user-defined functions, and things specific to `SQL Server`, e.g. the built-in functions and the full-text indices.

In my Jenkins CI build, I have an integration test suite that would test this layer using `NUnit`. To ensure tests are isolated from each other, the database initialisation should happen on the `[SetUp]` method.

I went through several options to implement the integration test:

1. Use in-memory database. Pros: test setup is fast, running test logic is fast. 
   Cons: this is a non-option, because the SQL commands that I use are specific to `SQL Server`.
2. Use `SQLite` or `SQL Compact`. Pros: syntax is similar to `SQL Server`, setting up and tearing down is just a matter of deleting files. Cons: also non-option the moment I start making use of user-defined functions and full-text index.
3. Use local `SQL Express` server just to serve the test. Pros: behaviour is almost guaranteed to match production setup, including built-in functions and full-text index. Cons: set up is slower and more complicated.

I went with option 3, with the following approach:

1. On `[SetUpFixture]`'s `[SetUp]`, initialise a seed database. Once initialised, create a backup of this database, save it as a file. This only happens once on the whole namespace of the tests.
2. On each `[TestFixture]`'s `[SetUp]`, restore the backup. Since this happens every time before a test is run, each test is isolated from the other tests.

The disadvantage is running the test suite now becomes very slow. Step no. 2 above takes 2-5 seconds for every test. On top of that, each test also takes some time to execute the test fixture itself, which is quite a bit slower that typical unit test because it hits real database.

In my current state, a moderately-sized test suite of 143 tests takes 13 minutes on my build machine, which is a VM on Azure, specced as A3 (4 cores 7 GB), running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there anyway that I can speed up this process other than pumping more hardware to the machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a transaction scope in the setup and dispose this in the teardown method:

```
[MyFixture]
public class MyTests
{
    private string connString= "...";
    private TransactionScope ts= null;
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required);
    }
    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        ts.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // do my tests etc.
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec MyProcecure"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Assert.Greater(retval, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This will work even if the unit under test has it's own transaction scope.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(VS.90).aspx)

> **Voting inside a nested scope**
>
> Although a nested scope can join the
> ambient transaction of the root scope, calling Complete in the nested
> scope has no affect on the root scope. Only if all the scopes from the
> root scope down to the last nested scope vote to commit the
> transaction, will the transaction be committed.

Comment: What happens if the unit under test has its own transaction scope and does a commit to DB? Would the outer transaction scope rolls back what was committed by the inner scope?

Comment: @AdityaSantoso yes a nested transaction will be rolled back. See update to answer.

Comment: It seems like I cannot read uncommitted data using this approach. Do I need to change anything in the connection or transaction scope or in the SQL command itself?

Comment: As long as you are using the same connection and haven't closed / committed / rolled back you should be able to read any uncommitted data.

Comment: I think I know why my reads could not read the uncommitted writes. TransactionScope doesn't play well with async-await, and my whole repository layer and the test method itself are full of async-await. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543254/get-transactionscope-to-work-with-async-await?lq=1
Once I turn my test method synchronous, it seems to have the intended effect. 
I will also see whether I can upgrade my application to .NET 4.5.1 to make use of `TransactionAsyncFlowOption`, because turning hundreds of tests that are implemented as async into non-async is going to be a bit tiring

Comment: Another thing is that since my application runs against `Azure SQL`, I applied `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` to my `DbContext`. Thing is, it cannot work together with `TransientScope`. To make it work with `TransientScope`, I had to suspend the execution strategy as mentioned in this blog: http://romiller.com/2013/08/19/ef6-suspendable-execution-strategy/