# TransactionTimeOut Exception on all DB hits made by a thread on which there was "A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread.." exception

Tags: c#, async-await, transactionscope

In production all of the sudden we started to have Exception message was **"A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created."**. Looking into code it was clear we are having .Net Transaction within the async method and TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled is **Not** used in TransactionScope. What interesting was somehow the above aborted transaction that caused Exception remains attached to the Thread and every API request served by that Thread causes **TransactionTimeOut Exception** on every db interaction.

I tried to reproduce issue on local by small program. If we see breakpoint we have transaction outside transaction scope. (its not every time , its only for the threads for which exception occurs)
[image]

My question is why transaction remains with the thread?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var loopResult = TxIssue();
        while (!loopResult.IsCompleted)
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static ParallelLoopResult TxIssue()
    {
        return Parallel.For(0, 10, async t =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (Transaction.Current != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"threadId : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Transaction status = {Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier}");
                }
                using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
                {
                    await Task.Delay(300);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you `await` an asynchronous operation, the current thread is freed up to be used by other operations. So one of your early threads might create a transaction on Thread #1, and then when it hits the `await` the delegate will return a Task that hasn't completed yet. The transaction scope is still associated with Thread #1, but Thread #1 is considered available for other tasks, so the `Parallel.For` might reuse Thread #1 to invoke another instance of the delegate.

I haven't tested this, but [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17527759/120955) the fix is to specify that you want to use the async flow in an optional argument to the TransactionScope.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(
                   TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                   TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
```

That tells the TransactionScope to associate itself with the async context instead of the Thread. Then, when the `await` causes the async context to get disassociated from the Thread, it will also cause the TransactionScope to get removed. And when the awaited task completes, even if its continuation happens on a different thread, the TransactionScope will become associated with the thread the continuation runs on.

Comment: Thats exactly the question is why Thread#1 still having the transaction , ITs not necessary same thread would execute after await

Comment: yes TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled fixed the problem then we dont have any Exception just curious to understand why this is happening? Was it bug in .Net or what

Comment: @yochauhan: It's because unless you specify otherwise, the TransactionScope associates itself with a Thread rather than an async context. So when the `await` makes Thread #1 available in the thread pool, it _does not_ remove the TransactionScope from that thread.

Comment: Last Paragraph of https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3419